# に in 両親に行ったように反乱軍に跪いてみせた

Tags: grammar, particle-に

> 彼はひとたまりもなくかつて両親に行ったように反乱軍に跪いてみせた。

[no real context, only an example sentence for 跪く](http://yourei.jp/%E8%B7%AA%E3%81%8F)

反乱軍に跪く is more obvious, kneeling at/towards 反乱軍.

両親に行った I'm far less certain of.

How should I look at this?

Comment: The context is [this](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%83%95%E3%82%A7%E3%83%AB%E3%83%8A%E3%83%B3%E3%83%897%E4%B8%96_(%E3%82%B9%E3%83%9A%E3%82%A4%E3%83%B3%E7%8E%8B)#%E3%82%B9%E3%83%9A%E3%82%A4%E3%83%B3%E7%AB%8B%E6%86%B2%E9%9D%A9%E5%91%BD) about *Ferdinand VII of Spain*? ...(中略) 「それはやがて1812年憲法復活を要求する巨大な暴動となりフェルナンドはすぐに捕らえられた。**彼はひとたまりもなくかつて両親に行ったように反乱軍に跪いてみせた**。だがあくまで権力の座にしがみつこうとしたフェルナンドは裏でイエズス会に協力を要請...」

Comment: i'm more focused on 両親に行った in particular than the overall context, not sure if that extra context helps in that regard.

Comment: You have three「に」could be parsed in your title and it's not so obvious which one is paticulary mentioned. However, you can decide to cancel or fix my edit suggestion.

Comment: @xyz You were reading the 行った as いった("went"), and not おこなった("did"), perhaps? And it caused your confusion, no?

Comment: @Chocolate, no i was thinking of 両親に with the に being "as (ie in the role of) ",  so he knelt in in front of the rebels in as if he was doing his parent's role or something like that. but i havn't seen it used in that way so i wasn't sure. Didn't realize it was him kneeling like he knelt in front of his parents.

Comment: @kimiTanaka, i thought i narrowed which に i was looking at in the description, but i guess it was less clear than i anticipated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are multiple にs in your sample sentence, and it's not clear which one you're asking about, so let's just look at the whole thing.

#### Breaking it down

Here's your whole sentence, with furigana added.

> 彼【かれ】はひとたまりもなくかつて両親【りょうしん】に行【おこな】ったように反乱軍【はんらんぐん】に跪{ひざまず}いてみせた。

What is this at its simplest?

We break out the topic marked by the は, and the main verb at the end.

> 彼【かれ】はひとたまりもなくかつて両親【りょうしん】に行【おこな】ったように反乱軍【はんらんぐん】に跪【ひざまず】いてみせた。
>   彼【かれ】は　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　跪【ひざまず】いてみせた。
>   彼【かれ】は ... 跪【ひざまず】いてみせた。
>     He ... bent the knee.

Okay.  So we know that much: this is the core of the statement.  The other pieces are descriptors that tell us more about the scene and context.

Breaking these out, we might parse the sentence like this:

> 彼【かれ】は　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　跪【ひざまず】いてみせた。
>   　　ひとたまりもなく
>   　　　　　　　　　　かつて両親【りょうしん】に行【おこな】ったように
>   　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　反乱軍【はんらんぐん】に

Let's look at each of these descriptor pieces in turn.

> ひと たまり　 も　　なく
>     one build-up `[EVEN]` not-ly →
>     without a single pause, without any resistance

This appears to be an idiomatic phrase.  On its own, たまり has various meanings that don't lend themselves to this idiom in any immediately obvious fashion ("a kind of soy sauce", "a hang-out for taxi drivers", etc. ).  Looking more at the underlying verb たまる, we see meanings like "to build up, to accumulate", and by extension, "to hold out, to hang on", which is more where this idiom comes from.

> かつて　両親【りょうしん】　　に　 行【おこな】った　よう　に
>     formerly parents `[TO]` performed way `[IN]` →
>     in the way [he] formerly did to his parents, like he used to do to his parents

This has two of the に particles.  The first one is on 両親【りょうしん】, and indicates the direction of the action.  The second is on よう, and is the adverbial に.  As the phrase ように, this indicates "in that fashion, in that way, in that manner".

> 反乱軍【はんらんぐん】　　　に
>     rebel army `[TO]`

This に is again a directional, indicating toward whom the action was performed.

---

Please comment if the above analysis does not address your question.

Comment: the only thing that i still wondering is,  if you saw 彼はひとたまりもなくかつて両親に行ったように and the page ended there,do you obviously know that 両親に is towards before you turned the page? Or is everything still up in the air at that point (cause, role, purpose, etc)?

Comment: @xyz, the に there would still be directional, since we have the verb 行った.  The only ambiguity might be whether the verb would be 行【い】った "went" or 行【おこな】った "did, performed, carried out", as that might depend on the meaning in the later clause on the next page.  Even just from the context of this first half of the sentence, we can tell that the verb should probably be 行【おこな】った, since 行【い】った doesn't quite make sense.  For either verb, though, the に would still be directional.